# A circle inscribed in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

> A circle is inscribed inside a trapezoid $ABCD$ ($AB || CD$). $M, N,
> P, Q$ are the midpoints of the sides $AB, BC, CD, AD$, respectively. If $AD = d$
>   and $BC=c$, express the perimeter of $MNPQ$. (Answer: $c + d$)

I think that $P = \frac {AC}{2} + \frac {DB}{2} + \frac {AC}{2} + \frac{DB}{2} = AC + DB.$ I do not know how to express it in a different way using $d$ and $c$. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the result in the text is wrong (consider $ABCD$ to be a square).

Comment: $c,d$ are diagonals or sides of the trapez?!

Comment: Yeah, I also think so. There's a misunderstanding with this problem.  It was '$M, N, P, Q$ are the midpoints of it sides $AB, BD, CD, AC$'. I fixed it because $BD$ is not a side (also $AC$).

Comment: The sides are $AB, BC,CD,{\color{red}{AC}}$?!

Comment: I did it, and even reloaded the page, however the text still mentions the side $AC$, which makes no sense, the same AC is also in the comment-

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. I thought I'd fixed it.

Comment: Ok, now it's obvious that your answer is correct and the one given in the text isn't, and you can see this using the triangular inequality.

Comment: In this case, the result is **not valid**. The already mentioned special case of a square shows it. (Sometimes people denote the parallel sides with $a,b$, and the diagonals with $c,d$, well, only in this case the result has the chance...)

Comment: The midpoint parallelogram's perimeter **is not equal** to the sum of the trapezoid's lateral edges. The perimeter **is equal** to the sum of the diagonals; indeed, each side of the parallelogram is half the length of the corresponding parallel diagonal. But the latter is true of *any* quadrilateral, not just inscriptable trapezoids.

Comment: The solution in the book makes sense if the order of vertices is $ABDC $, so that $AD $ and $BC $ are the diagonals. The inconsistence has appeared after you "fixed" an alledged error in the problem statement.